# LibGDX Crash when destroying a body?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

So I'm working on a LibGDX game, and when a bullet body collides with a block, I want to destroy the bullet. I'm calling:

```
Globals.gameMan.world.destroyBody(bullet.body);
```

and for whatever reason, the entire game crashes after this. I'm given a message with the option to debug twice, and when I click it, nothing happens. Thank you, and sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't destroy a body inside the cycle of Box2d World. You need to mark that body to be destroyed and destroy it after the `world.step()` is finished executing. Get an array of bodies to be destroyed and  destroy them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not calling `World.destroyBody` passing a `Body` that has already been destroyed.

Also, from where are you calling `World.destroyBody`, if it's from a **Box2D** call-back (a collision handler, for example) you are not allowed to destroy bodies. If that is the case you need to make note of the `Body` to destroy and then destroy it outside of the call-back.